# Absolutness, need for some clarifications and examples.

Tags: set-theory

I have some trouble in understanding the definition of absoluteness.Let $M$ be a (transitive) model of $ZFC$. A formula $\phi(x)$ is said to be absolute if $\forall x \in M (\phi(x)^M\leftrightarrow \phi(x)^V)$, where $V$ is the Von Neumann universe. I know that it is in general possible to have $\phi(x)^M$ true but $\phi(x)^V$ false. For example $card(x)^M$ can be true (i.e. $x$ is a cardinal number inside the model $M$ but since when we are inside $V$ we add bijections because we are in a bigger class, so maybe x will be in bijection with something smaller than him so he will not be a cardinal number anymore. But is it possible that we have that $\phi(x)^V$ holds but $\phi(x)^M$ doesn't hold?
Second, I was told that "being an uncountable ordinal" is not absolute. So what would be a model where that would be an example for this?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if $\varphi$ is true in $M$ but not $V$, then $\neg\varphi$ is true in $V$ but not $M$. So every failure of upwards absoluteness has a corresponding failure of downwards absoluteness.

As to the second question, if $M$ is any countable transitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ then $\omega_1^M$ is countable but $M$ thinks $\omega_1^M$ is an uncountable cardinal.

Comment: Very nice. I hadn't thought about taking the negation. For the second part of the answer, there is two things I still don't understand.  First, when we say "$\omega_1^M$ is countable" it is like a shortcut for saying "$V$ thinks $\omega_1$ is countable" right? Second, suppose $x\in M$ is the element satisfying $(\omega_1(x))^M$. Then since $x\in$ M, and $M$ is countable, it seems intuitive to me that $x$ will be countable but in $V$ but what is the argument to affirm this?